# Strange things with Winsock2 and system start command

Tags: c++, windows, process, winsock2

There is a program

```
#include <Winsock2.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <thread>

const uint16_t ANY_VALID_PORT = 12345;
SOCKET sock = INVALID_SOCKET;

void listenPort()
{
    sockaddr_in addr {};
    int addrSize = sizeof(addr);
    accept(sock, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrSize);
}

// #define CORRECT_SEQUENCE

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData = { 0 };
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    sockaddr_in clientService {};
    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    clientService.sin_port = htons(ANY_VALID_PORT);
    clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    bind(sock, (SOCKADDR*)&clientService, sizeof(clientService));
    listen(sock, 2);

#ifdef CORRECT_SEQUENCE
    system("start cmd");
    std::thread listening { listenPort };
#else
    std::thread listening { listenPort };
    system("start cmd"); //could be virtually any program
#endif

    closesocket(sock);
    listening.join();

    WSACleanup();
}
```

Expected behavior: the program finishes while cmd continues to run in a separate window.
Real behavior: the program doesn't finish until the new cmd is closed.
When CORRECT_SEQUENCE is defined, it works just fine. But without it, accept() doesn't return even if sock is closed. The debugger tells us that we are stuck up on join().

What is the reason for this dependency? cmd (or even empty program with only while(1); in the main()) have nothing with our port.

Comment: `system` will not return until the command you run exits.

Comment: And don't close the socket until the thread have exited (and the `join` call have returned). You have a data-race with two threads using the same shared data simultaneously without protection or synchronization. That leads to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 1):

> [*A socket handle created by the **WSASocket** or the **socket**
> function is inheritable by default.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-socket)

the `system` start process with [`CreateProcessA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) with `bInheritHandles = TRUE`. as result `sock` is duplicated to child process.

`accept` return control, when **last** handle to `sock` closed, but after `system("start cmd");` exist another `sock` handle in `cmd`. only after you close cmd - accept return with error (probably `WSAEINTR` )

also the the both variants of your code is wrong. and both not work. you also can call `closesocket(sock);` before call `accept`. so all is wrong.

also `system("start cmd");` is extermally not efficient. this call `CreateProcessA` for *cmd.exe* with command line */c start cmd* - so first cmd run second cmd and exit..

1. use `WSASocketW` with `WSA_FLAG_NO_HANDLE_INHERIT` but never `socket`
2. never use `system`. use `CreateProcessW`.
3. not call `cmd /c start cmd`. if you need cmd - just exec `cmd`
4. not pass handle ( `sock` ) to another thread and in parallel close it